# Requested URL gets appended when using getJSON in PhoneGap

Tags: jquery, json, cordova, getjson

When I test my PhoneGap app in Google Chrome and tries to fetch some JSON via jQuery's $.getJSON, my URL-vars (query string) gets appended twice in some strange way. There is no problem with accessing my webserver that returns the JSON, but when I do this:

```
 $.getJSON("http://api.myserver.com/project/?x=getAll&usrId=60", function(data) {
 }
```

And then log the request on the server I get that the following url has been requested:

```
http://api.myserver.com/project/?x=getAll&usrId=60/project/?x=getAll&usrId=60
```

As you see, everything following my domain name, is appended again after a slash at the end of the original url. Am I missing something here or what?

This off course messes up my evaluation of the url variables values on the web server. It only seems to happen when I call the web service from within my PhoneGap app (via Google Chrome). I have tried to call from another web server (cross-domain), but the problem does not appear then.

I have also tried to send the url vars as the data argument of the $.getJSON, but is has no effect - the url still gets appended.

Comment: You are sure you requested an absolute URL and not a relative one?

Comment: Yes, as far as I know, a url beginning with http:// is a absolute one?
It works if I paste the url into any browser

Comment: Hm. Are you using an .htaccess files? Maybe try disabling those for testing. And/or are you testing this locally?

Comment: I am not using any .htaccess files, but yes, I am testing it locally requesting an remote server. Sorry, forgot to mention that.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/ says: "Data that is sent to the server is appended to the URL as a query string. If the value of the data parameter is a plain object, it is converted to a string and url-encoded before it is appended to the URL."
Does that has something to do with it?

Comment: I downloaded the PhoneGap shell app from Apple Store to my iPhone, that is on the same local network, and when i connect to my app in the shell app it works! So this is a browser issue then. Google Chrome and Firefox has the same issue. Can anyone explain this?
I have a push notification service integrated in the app also (straight from the tutorial on phonegap.com), can this cause this behaviour? I mean, the push api is not supported by the browsers, as also is noticed in the console log.